# Linking to a specific group of products

Tags: extensions, product-list

I've been searching for a few days now for a solution to this.
Lets say I have a block on the front page, and click on it. It should then take me to a page with a group of specifically selected products, shown just like a category page (the products can be selected from the list of all products).

Is it possible to find an extension that does this? Or do I have to code it myself?

Regards, Adam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1: Build a category page, don't show it in the navigation.

Solution 2: The alternative is: build a CMS page, embed a block with all products from a category.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/248/display_products_on_home_page

Is there any reason, why not use a category, not shown in the navigation?

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of that.. Thanks!